# tinymce textarea editor

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine, tinymce

I am using Tiny MCE which is a javascript file that allows you to turn textareas into more of an editor interface.  I just downloaded the file from the website http://www.tinymce.com/index.php and I am having problems setting it up.  At the simplest level do I only need the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",    
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

And then the tiny_mce.js file in my project.  Or do I need other files in my project?  By the way I am using eclipse to write a google app engine project in python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a closing `</script>` tag here, which is not allowing javascript to run properly.

It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry about the messiness of that post I meant to codify it but then forgot what I was doing.  I actually had that in my code I just forgot to put it on here.  I just double checked and everything is the same now.

Comment: did you followed the installation process properly, I mean as per http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation.

Comment: yes but after unzipping all the files it is not clear if I need to include all of the files in my project or just the javascript

Comment: well I found the for dummies section and apparently it is titled correctly because it got the job done. thanks though!  Here it is for posterity: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22

Comment: as a final ad-on this is much much faster and easier to install:  http://nicedit.com/ though doesn't have as many options